# Is it possible to send message to Azure Event Hubs using MassTransit Azure Service Bus transport?

Tags: masstransit, azure-eventhub

MassTransit 3 has support for Azure Service Bus transport, but is it possible to configure an Azure Event Hubs endpoint rather than Azure Service Bus queue as the MassTransit endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit currently does not support Event Hub.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the info.

Comment: @chris-patterson is this still the current situation? I can see the following at the MassTransit docs:
https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html#event-hub